# How can I hide content I've created using the :before pseudo selector when a HTML text element is empty?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a chat bubble with CSS and HTML.

If there is no text in the chat bubble I do not want it to display.

I can get body of the chat bubble to go away using `:empty` but I cannot get the triangle part of the chatbox to disappear because it was created with the pseudo selector `:before` and content: `' '`.

My code is below. Is there anyway to make this little triangle go away if the `h4` element is empty?

```css
/* CSS talk bubble */

.myFeedback h4:empty {
  display: none;
}

.talk-bubble {
  margin-top: 220px;
  left: 390px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: purple;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tri-right.right-in:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: -20px;
  top: 38px;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 12px solid;
  border-color: purple transparent transparent purple;
}


/* talk bubble contents */

.talktext {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.talktext p {
  /* remove webkit p margins */
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
}


/* end of talk bubble stuff */
```

```html
<div class="myFeedback">
  <div id='guess-feedback' class="talk-bubble tri-right round right-in">
    <h4 class="talktext"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One way to do this, would be to replace `.tri-right.right-in:before {` with `.tri-right.right-in > h4:before {`, so the triangle is inside the h4 and gets hidden too (:empty is not affected by :before). I tried it in JSFiddle and it seems to work fine, no other CSS changes should be necessary. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3e9g6my/

Comment: @elveti this comment should really be an answer.

Comment: @elveti Thanks so much. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```css
/* CSS talk bubble */

h4:empty {
  display: none;
}

.talk-bubble {
  margin-top: 220px;
  left: 390px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: purple;
}

.round{
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tri-right.right-in h4:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  left: auto;
    right: -20px;
  top: 38px;
    bottom: auto;
    border: 12px solid;
    border-color: purple transparent transparent purple;
}
/* talk bubble contents */
.talktext{
  padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.talktext p{
  /* remove webkit p margins */
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
}

/* end of talk bubble stuff */
```

```html
 <div class="myFeedback">
  <div id='guess-feedback' class="talk-bubble tri-right round right-in">
    <h4 class="talktext"></h4>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="myFeedback">
  <div id='guess-feedback' class="talk-bubble tri-right round right-in">
    <h4 class="talktext">With Text</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change below code in your CSS

**From:**

```
.tri-right.right-in:before
```

**To**

```
.tri-right.right-in h4:before
```